# circuits and differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

[image]

Consider the parallel circuit in the figure with $~R = 20 ~\omega ,~~ C = \frac{1}{5}~F~$ and $~L = 5~H~$ with initial conditions $~iL=-1A~$ and $~Vc(0)= 4V~$ find the voltage $~v(t)~$.

So according to me to solve the problem I need $~V0=R1i+L\frac{di}{dt} +V~$ and $~i=Cdv/dt~$ obtaining from sustien $$ ~V0 = R1\left(C\frac{dv}{dt}\right)+L\frac{d}{dt}\left(C\frac{dv}{dt}\right) +V = R1CV'+LCV''+V= LCV''+R1CV'+V= r^2+ar+b=0~$$ getting an homogeneus differential equation and getting the roots but I'm not using the initial V and I.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Just rejected your edit to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3245838/probability-and-physics-application-problem-voltages/3245863#3245863), if you wish to ask questions, ask directly. Please don't unnecessarily edit the answers which result in deviation from the intended sense.

Comment: Applying KCL, you should get $$V'' + \dfrac{1}{RC}V'+\dfrac{1}{LC}V=0$$
Then you can use the initial conditions to solve the constants.

Comment: Thanks i got the answer https://www.academia.edu/38170834/Ejercicios_resueltos_Ctos_RLC_segundo_orden